# Mule Plugin for Maven

Tags: maven, mule

I'm using the mule-maven-plugin as explained here: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/mule-maven-plugin#running-integration-tests , using "mvn deploy" will donwload the mule 3.7.2 to the target folder but standalone won't fire up, instead it throws this error

```
The Mule Enterprise Edition service was launched, but failed to start.
```

If i manually trigger the mule.bat everything works as expected and standalone is able to run the projects on the app/ folder.

Logs: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B-RSwLHJZLJqckJESVJpMEJqeUU&usp=sharing

Comment: can you attach the complete exception trace or log that would provide adequate information to see the reason?

Comment: Can you run mvn clean deploy -X -e and paste Maven console log and Mule server log?

Comment: Hello @AleSequeira just updated with the full logs files

Comment: @Shanky_Gupta updated, thanks

Comment: @AleSequeira updated the error.log,if you got time to check it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Carlos, I see a couple of thigs in the logs:

1. Unable to install the Mule Enterprise Edition service - El servicio especificado ya existe. (0x431)

Probably you already have a Mule service running, can you try stopping it before running the plugin?

2. [INFO] Using MULE_HOME: C:\cygwin64\home\Carlos Parra\workspace\mule\dummy-project\target\mule-enterprise-standalone-3.7.2

If (1) doesn't solve the problem can you try to use a directory without spaces?

Please tell me if this works.

Comment: I do not understand Spanish but, when I translated El servicio especificado ya existe it pointed to the same thing that Ale has mentioned. That could probably be the reason for that.

Comment: Also, the log shows many dependencies could not be resolved and hence the JARs could not be downloaded and put into project. Try one more thing to keep them updated by forcing snapshot update of all your Maven dependencies. Right click on project > Maven > Update project > Force update.

Comment: @AleSequeira ok i just noticed that the plugin installs Mule as a windows service so i had to add my local user credentials to that service, now it fails during undeploy, looks like it's trying to remove the app/project folder during runtime instead of removing the .txt file to stop the application, i have updated the log file, if you don't mind taking a look thank you Ale

Comment: @Carlos, the mule log still says that there already exists a service with that name: Unable to install the Mule Enterprise Edition service - El servicio especificado ya existe. (0x431)
Starting the Mule Enterprise Edition service...